# QGIS action on layer scope - reference to layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, actions

In QGIS I would like to create an action of type "python" on layer scope, aim of this simple action is to print out the selected feature of the layer the action is defined on:

[image]

My simple question is: How do I refer to the layer the action is defined on in the python code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used this approach in Python actions previously to get a reference to a `QgsMapLayer` object and it works well:

```py
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
```